# Constructing a sequence so every contiguous subsequence of $5$ is unique

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, puzzle

> Construct a sequence of $36$ integers using just $1$'s and $0$'s so
>   that every subsequence of length $5$ is unique (or explain why no such
>   sequence exists).

I think that the answer is possible since there are $2^{5} = 32$ possible sequences of length $5$, and we're looking at $5$ at a time. So we'll look at exactly $32$ sequences. I've been having trouble constructing this though. I think that we need to use the binary representations of all numbers between $0$ and $31$.

I started with something like this:

$$0000010$$

Because first we're looking at $0$ then $1$ then $2$. But it gets strange for $3$ since I need two consecutive numbers. So I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: These are called [De Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Matlab script to check for duplicate sequences, and then just kept adding zeroes unless this resulted in a doubly occurring sequence, in which case I added one. I had to backtrack a few times too.

$0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0$

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an explanation on how to construct this? I'm trying to come up with a reason.

Comment: I basically described my algorithm. Just add zeros if you can, add a one if you can't add a zero, and backtrack to the last added zero and change to a one (if possible) if you get stuck.

Comment: I think it should be easier going from right to left. There should be no need for backtracking if I am not mistaken. (And I am, actually.)

Comment: Note that this particular example would make a circle of $32$ digits if you wrap it round, so you can begin with any chosen five digit sequence by cutting the circle at the desired point. Note also that the complement of this sequence gives a different sequence from the original or its reverse, so there are at least two distinct solutions for any five digit start.